# HTTP API development: what should be the HTTP status code logic to be used?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

while developing some REST APIs I came into a logic question for which I don't have a clear answer.

Let's say I'm developing an API that a user can use to retrieve some data from a backend (e.g. object storage).

Usually the API gives back `status code 200` and the object is transferred to the user.

However, if the requested object isn't present, what should the API give back as an error code?

Two potential solutions here:

1. Gives back `200` as it represents the API functionality itself, which worked well, and a message error in the response body where there's written `404 file not found`
2. Gives back `404` as the files couldn't be retrieved

What should be the standard to be followed? Logically I'd say the #2 is the most obvious answer, however I've seen products like Elasticsearch which behaves like the #1.

The explanation I get from the people claiming the #1 should be the correct one is that the status code should be representing the functionality of the API itself, and it gives back `200` as the API worked as expected, however no object could be found.

The explanation I get from the people claiming the #2 is that giving back `200` is just misleading, they don't care if the API worked well or not, as if it wouldn't work well it would just give `50x` error at some point.

In your opinion what should be the logic to be followed? Is there any standard I can refer to?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I'm developing an API that a user can use to retrieve some data from a backend (e.g. object storage).

> However, if the requested object isn't present, what should the API give back as an error code?

Important idea: your *resource* model is not the same as your *data* model.

HTTP is concerned with resources, and representations of resources.  You can look to RFC 9110 for an [explanation of resources](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-resources), but it may be more useful to look to Roy Fielding's [definition](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1):

> Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource.

If you think of the different kinds of "resources" we regularly access on the web (web pages, images, style sheets, scripts).  My recommendation is to start from the notion of "document", but recognize that the resource concept can be more general.

Now, the status code in an HTTP response is metadata of the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.  The audience for that metadata is the collection of general purpose HTTP components on the web (browsers, caches, crawlers, etc).

Among other things, the use of status code provides a hint as to what payload the HTTP response is carrying: is it a representation of a resource? is it instead an [explanation of an error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-client-error-4xx)?

If you imagine a text document as a resource, it's clear that the contents of that document could be anything, including a sequence of characters that is indistinguishable from an error message (we got an error message, saved it as a file, and are now serving that file from our web server).  The way that the server communicates to the world that these bytes are actually the data from the file is by using a successful status code (2xx).

[HTTP GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-get) is the method we use to fetch the current representation of a resource.  But whether or not a resource has a current representation, and how that is determined, are implementation details hidden behind the uniform HTTP interface.

The fact that your back end storage has no object that matches the key computed from your resource identifier might mean that the corresponding resource has no representation at all (4xx), or it might mean that the resource has a "blank" representation (in whatever way that blank makes sense in your resource model).

There isn't a single right answer here, because all resource models are not the same; we aren't choosing what kinds of HTTP responses to send based on what is "best", but rather on what is "best fit" for the interaction model we are using (which might change from one resource to another even within the same resource model).